# Aircraft Thrust to weight ratio contradiction with energy conservation

Tags: energy-conservation, aerodynamics, rocket-science, aircraft, lift

Usually, airliners have (Thrust/Weight) T/W ratio in the range of 0.2 to 0.8

and for steady flight W = lift

My question is, for example, that Antonov 225 has Thrust/weight: 0.234 for max takeoff weight

```
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonov_An-225_Mriya
```

Then doesn't this defy energy conservation, or Newtons Third Law as engine's input is 229.5 kN each of all 6 engines and [ Max takeoff weight: 640,000 kg or 640*9.81 KN = lift for steady flight].

T/W = [229.5*6/(640*9.81)]  = 0.22 approx.

Please, I need the theory to solve such problem

Comment: You don't need a giant airplane to understand this. Make a paper airplane and throw it. Once you let go, it has *zero* forward thrust. Even so, it glides and maintains its speed, though it loses altitude gradually. Once an airplane has been accelerated to flying speed, all the engine thrust (minus drag) does is determine the angle of ascent or descent.

Comment: in a winged aircraft engine thrust IS NOT total lift

Answer (score 2):

Lift is approximately proportional to velocity squared of the aircraft, not the thrust. That is why runways are required.

So the thrust is used the accelerate the aircraft to take-off velocity, which will produce enough lift to overcome gravity.

Also, the fact that the thrust is less than the gravity in Antonov implies that it can't do this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW28Mb1YvwY

Comment: Lift is proportional to velocity *squared*. It is also proportional to angle of attack, for small angles.

Comment: Oh, of course. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

You say that for steady flight weight equals lift. That's correct.

Then you ask how thrust can be less than weight.

Do you see how you are confusing lift and thrust? There is no rule that says thrust must equal weight, or that lift must equal thrust, so there is no problem. If L = W and W > T, then the conclusion is that lift is simply that L > T. Lift is greater than thrust.

Answer (score 1):

There is no contradiction here. In a steady wings level flight lift and weight are acting in vertical plane. Since they are equal in magnitude, there is no acceleration in vertical plane. Thrust is merely there to overcome drag and keep the plane moving at constant speed forward. Thrust and drag are equal and thus in a steady wings level flight, there is no acceleration in horizontal plane either. In trying to simplify I've ignored the pitching moments, contribution of stabilizer and changes in weight of the ac with time as fuel is consumed.

Thrust to weight ratio in excess of 1 is usually desirable for fighter jets where manoeuvring in vertical plane is required.

Comment: Also, in the latest edit one user has drawn thrust in direction opposite to flight path.. thrust acts forward and drag acts against it. Some clarity would appear if a correct depiction of forces is drawn.

Answer (score -2):

Yes - you are correct. There is a problem:  Thrust-to-weight ratios contradict the claim lift equals the weight of the airplane (Lift = Weight). This is summarised in the attached image.

[image]

For example, airliners (such as Anntoonv 225, Boeing 747 and Airbus 320) have thrust-to-weight ratios of about 0.3; as you correctly mention.

This means that in stable flight, the thrust from the engines is just 0.3x the weight of the airplane. For example, if thrust is 1.0 N, then the weight is 3.3 N.

Then if Lift = Weight was true, lift would also be 3.3 N, which is 3.3x the thrust from the engines.

See image.

But this is impossible. The lift generated by the wings is not observed to be 3.3x greater than the thrust produced by the en engines of an airliner. There is no explanation how this could be true.

Thrust-to-weight ratios are known and based on verifiable data of engine thrust and aircraft weight. Whereas, Lift = Weight an unproven assumption in almost every textbook (based on Newtons 2nd law of motion F = ma). Therefore, Lift = Weight is wrong:  Thrust-to-eight ratios demonstrate that the lift required by an airliner to fly, cannot equal its weight.

Comment: This doesn't follow logically.  You provide no good reason to doubt that the lift generated by the wings can be 3.3x the thrust of the aircraft, you just deny it without understanding the explanations.  Lift = Weight isn't "unproven"; we've been proving the principle behind it for centuries, and been proving it with planes for decades.  If you know the mass of the aircraft, you know the minimum lift required to raise it, and that's basically introductory physics.

Comment: Where is the proof that Lift = Weight?  I cannot find any experiment for this. It's always an assumption. I don't mind either way if Lift = Weight or not, I just cannot find the proof.

Comment: "But this is impossible. The lift generated by the wings is not observed to be 3.3x greater than the thrust" I would just point out that gliders produce non-zero lift with zero thrust (infinite times greater), so there is nothing even remotely "impossible" about having lift greater 3.3 times greater than thrust.

Comment: In flight, an airliner's wings are not producing 3.3x the thrust from the engines. This can be proved by standing behind an airliner's engines (at a safe distance). Then stand the same distance under the wings of an airliner taking off.

Comment: @NickLandell It comes from the basic principles of physics.  Weight accelerates the plane down, so you need an equal force to keep it up, which is lift.  If lift was less than weight, airplanes wouldn't be in the air, gravity would keep them grounded, or bring them tragically down to the ground if they managed to get into the air with lift < weight.

Comment: But you're still arguing theory. I'm asking for the experimental proof. Can we at least agree that there's no experimental proof that Lift = Weight ?

Comment: @NickLandell There are _mountains_ of experimental proof that this has to apply.  Requiring and equal and opposite force opposed to gravity is something that we know experimentally from centuries of physics studies.  There's extreme experimental proof that lift must equal weight because we understand how forces work, and defined lift and weight in such a way that they must be at least equal for the plane to maintain altitude.

Comment: If you are correct just provide one experiment which proves that Lift = Weight.

Comment: @NickLandell There are plenty of experiments on this.  Just searching "measuring lift in wind tunnel" gives experiments where they are able to find the lift by measuring the change in force on the object in the vertical direction when the wind is on.  They get the lift values they would expect if lift=weight, and this method is used to help improve plane designs.

Comment: @NickLandell every single time an airplane measures that it is flying with a constant altitude is an experimental proof that weight = lift. Or are you seriously suggesting that Newton’s 2nd law doesn’t apply to airplanes?

Comment: Correct, I'm asking if Lift = Weight. Wind tunnel experiments aren't sufficiently realistic, as they don't allow for air to be pushed down and circulated as seen in airliners flying through clouds. Aircraft manufacturers design airplanes using lift coefficients, not an absolute value for lift.

Comment: @NickLandell If wind tunnel measurements aren't sufficient, I'm not sure if there's any satisfying you.  As mentioned, the most obvious "experiment" that shows lift=weight is literally just flying an actual plane and maintaining altitude.  In that way you could say most planes flying are successful experiments.  It really comes down to basic physics of forces.  In level flight, lift is the opposite force vector of weight, so if it is not accaelerating up or down, lift must equal weight.

Comment: Why include gravity when calculating Lift (Lift = Weight = Mass x Gravity); when gravity is not included in the standard textbook equation for lift: 

LIFT    =  0.5 x Aircraft Velocity2 x  Wing Area x Air Density  x  Lift Coefficient

Comment: So claiming that 'Lift = Weight' for airplanes contradicts the standard textbook equation for lift, as well as thrust-to-weight ratios for airplanes.

Comment: I did some calculations for lift, based on observations from videos of low flying jets. These showed that 'Lift = Weight' was implausible, and 'Lift => Mass' was feasible. You can find these calculations online, just google: "landell, Calculation of the air displaced down by a wing."

Comment: @NickLandell Okay, for starters, the equation "Lift = weight" is just a necessary condition for the plane to maintain altitude.  They do calculate the lift from the second equation (and experimental data from wind tunnels and such); and make sure that they have enough lift so that lift can counteract the weight due to gravity pulling the plane down.  As far as your last comment goes, that's total nonsense.  You say it's implausible that Lift = Weight; but somehow you think "Lift => Mass" makes sense, even though lift is a force and mass isn't, so you can't even equate them.